# Get Data from PHP in angular unhandled error

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, html

I get an error which doesn't say anything to me. I'm kinda new to Angular so it might be a really stupid error but I can't figure out.

It says there's a Syntax Error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token /
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:1252:14)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:9414:16)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:9505:12
at forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:336:20)
at transformData (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:9504:3)
at transformResponse (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:10276:23)
at processQueue (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:14745:28)
at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:14761:27
at Scope.$eval (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.js:15989:28)
```

My html Code where I'm calling the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="dbTestCtrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
      <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
      <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

My Angular controller:

```
module.controller('dbTestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get(PHP_API + "datahandler/dbTest.php")
   .then(function (response){
      $scope.names = response.data.records;});
});
```

And my php file which is working as far as i can see:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cmweb");

  $result = $conn->query("SELECT loginName, userID, createDate FROM users");

  $outp = "";
  while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {
        $outp .= ",";
    }
    $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $rs["loginName"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"ID":"'   . $rs["userID"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"Created":"'. $rs["createDate"]     . '"}'; 
  }
  $outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
  $conn->close();

  echo($outp);
?>
```

As I said I'm really new to angular and I just couldn't figure out by myself so it would be great if someone could help me out :)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

May be your json format is wrong. Try using json_encode to avoid writing all those quotes and brackets by yourself.

```
$outp = array();

while ($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $outp[] = array('Name' => $rs["loginName"], 
                    'ID' => $rs["userID"], 
                    'Created' => $rs["createDate"]);
}

echo json_encode(array('records' => $outp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the return

```
echo json_encode($outp);
```